# Need help reading a file that has a book format

Tags: c++11

I been struggling reading a file that has a book format. The file is broken into pages by a string that looks like this "---------------------------------------". What I'm trying to do is read all the words and keep track of the page number and the word number of every word, the file looks like this

[my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRSwU.png)

For example if the word "hello" appears in the first page it would looks like this " hello 1,1" because it's the first word on page one if the word would appear in the second page the output will be "hello 2,1"
This is the code I have so far

```
ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("GreatExpectations.txt");
    if(!inFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error, can't open the file....."<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    string word;
    string separator;
    separator = "----------------------------------------";
    int pageNum = 0, wordNum = 0;
    IndexMap myMap(200000);
    string title;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        getline(inFile, title);
        cout << title <<endl;
    }
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        inFile >> word;
        //cout << word << " ";
        wordNum++;
        if(word == separator)
            pageNum++;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't explained how you are struggling. Does the program crash at run time? Does it produce unexpected result? Add the additional info to the post to make it a [mcve].

Comment: It reads the file but I don't know how to keep track of the word's pages and word numbers as they appear. For example the word "Biddy" appears in the first page the output should be something like this( Biddy 1,1) or in the second pages for the word sake it should output this (sake 2, 6);

Comment: Add that info to the post. Also, add the missing code so that you have a [mcve], add the observed output so others can troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understood your question here is my approach to the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct WordInfo {
    string word;
    int pageNum;
    int wordNum;
};

int main() {
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("GreatExpectations.txt");

    if(!inFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error, can't open the file....."<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int pageNum = 1, wordNum = 0;
    vector<WordInfo> words; // container for words with informations

    // read the file line-by-line
    for(string line; getline(inFile, line);) {
        // detect the page separator which is a line from hyphens only 
        if(line.find_first_not_of("-") == string::npos) {
            pageNum++;
            wordNum = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // process the line word-by-word
        stringstream ss(line);
        for(string word; getline(ss, word, ' ');) {
            wordNum++;
            words.push_back({ word, pageNum, wordNum });
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `WordInfo` structure will hold informations from a word as you wanted. It's not the optimal but more simple to read the file line-by-line, so there is two loops: the first reads a line and the second reads the words from that line. If a word is read, it will be pushed into the `words` vector for later use. That's all.

Comment: It reads the words perfectly but for some reason doesn't update to the second page, the pageNum doesn't increase it stays on one.

Comment: In that case the separator line contains something else beside the hyphens, maybe some white spaces or a remainder from platform specific line endings or tabulator characters, etc.. You can specify these in the `find_first_not_of` function like: `find_first_not_of("- \r\n\t")`.